# Recursively parse Google search results using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm using the below CasperJS script to recursively parse the (multi-page) search results provided by google for the query `site:https://www.launchgood.com/project/`.

```
var links = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks() {
  var currentLinks = document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(currentLinks, function(e) {
    rawHref = e.getAttribute('href');
    urlPattern = /.*(https?[:/]+[^&]+).*/g;
    cleanHref = urlPattern.exec(rawHref);

    return cleanHref[1];
  });

  Array.prototype.push.apply(links, currentLinks);
  this.echo(' - ' + currentLinks.join('\n - '));
}

function parseAndContinue() {
  links = this.evaluate(getLinks);

  // now click 'Next'
  if(this.exists('a.fl')) {
    this.thenClick('a.fl');
    this.then(parseAndContinue);
  } else {
    this.exit();
  }
}

casper.start('http://google.com/ncr', function() {
  // search from google form
  this.fill('form[action="/search"]', 
    { q: 'site:https://www.launchgood.com/project/' }, true);
});

casper.then(parseAndContinue);
casper.run();
```

This seems to continually search the 2nd page, over and over again in a never-ending loop -- instead of advancing to the next page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, automated queries against Google were against their terms of service last time I checked. There are plenty of other search engines that allow this.

Comment: @ashes999 Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Your looks fine apart from not printing anything. `getLinks` is a function that is evaluated in the page context. `this` refers to the global object, which is `window`, inside of the page context. You have no access to `casper` inside of the page context, because it is *sandboxed* and only primitive objects can be passed in or out. It has no access to variables defined outside of it (no access to `links`).

```
function getLinks() {
  var currentLinks = document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(currentLinks, function(e) {
    var rawHref = e.getAttribute('href');
    var urlPattern = /.*(https?[:/]+[^&]+).*/g;
    var cleanHref = urlPattern.exec(rawHref);

    return cleanHref[1];
  });
}

function parseAndContinue() {
  var links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(links, undefined, 4));

  // now click 'Next'
  if(this.exists('a.fl')) {
    this.thenClick('a.fl');
    this.then(parseAndContinue);
  } else {
    this.exit();
  }
}
```

Additionally, no code after the `return` statement will be executed.
Please be more careful and don't create global variables left and right.